# Can I use Javascript to write Salesforce apps?

Tags: apex, javascript, javascript-remoting

I'm thinking of learning Salesforce, and I'm interested in figuring out how much of my HTML/CSS/Javascript knowledge transfers over.  I'm not familiar with APEX.

I'm looking at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_javascript_libraries.htm, and it looks like Javascript is fairly well supported.

So, based on that background, I'm wondering if someone could answer these questions for me:

1. Is Javascript support robust / mature enough to write apps in?
2. How much APEX do I *really* need to learn (if I'm creating apps from scratch; obviously legacy apps are a different beast)?
3. How does Salesforce1 fit into this picture, especially with respect to the Lightning Experience?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

On your point 2...

The new'ish [Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_migration_introduction/units/lex_migration_introduction_rightforme) user interface uses Lightning Components that are heavily based on JavaScript and in many cases Apex will be avoidable altogether. So if you are happy to ignore the large installed base using the older technologies you won't need to focus too much on Apex.

But note that the Lightning Components framework is not a container for arbitrary 3rd party JavaScript: rather it is a distinct JavaScript-based  platform in its own right that ties tightly into other Salesforce infrastructure.

In your point 1...

That is subject to opinion: with good unit tests in place (coming this summer for Lightning Components I believe) I would argue that yes it is. JavaScript frameworks such as Angular 1.x are in pretty widespread use. But defensive code is needed at the server-side against malicious users as the client-side is inherently open to tampering.

Comment: Thanks for the tip: I hadn't heard of the Lightning Experience yet.  I was focusing my reading/education on VisualForce.